# How to pass a array in local address space in Opencl kernel

Tags: c, opencl

I want to pass an array to the OpenCL kernel in local address space. But I get `CL_invalid_VALUE`.

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

We don't need to create a buffer to pass data in Local address space. So:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 21, sizeof(int)*5,a);
```

In Kernel

```
__kernel void abc(__local int *a)
{}
```

If i change the `__local` to `__global`, everything works fine. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: For start, replace `sizeof(int)*5` to `sizeof(a)`

Comment: I'm not up to speed on opencl, but if the nature and location of the pointed-to memory is indeed relevant, then you haven't provided enough information to determine that.  As always, we expect a [mcve], and your chances of getting a useful answer are greatly improved if you provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass anything to local memory from host.

The purpose of spesifying a local pointer in kernel parameters is to spesify the size of the local buffer at the runtime. Then on the `clSetKernelArg` call the 3rd parameter is the size and the 4th parameter must be NULL.[Documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html)

Assuming you are using GPU you can either pass it to Constant memory, initialize the local memory in the kernel if it's always the same or just pass it to global memory and then load it in the kernel to local memory preferably using  [async_work_group_copy.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html)

Comment: But we can pass data to private memory from host. And there is one book called "Opencl Programming guide" by "[Aaftab Munshi, Benedict Gaster, Timothy Mattson" , on page no. - 134 , they show it is possible to pass the elements to local memory from host.

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully clear any confusion you have.